# Evaluate $\displaystyle\int_1^e\left(x^x+\ln x^{\large x^x}\right)\ dx$

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals

I just took calculus test &  I cannot find

$$\int_1^e\left(x^x+\ln x^{x^x}\right)\ dx.$$

I don't know how to answer this integral. Can you help me? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Perhaps writing the integrand as $x^x(1+\ln x)$ helps finding the primitive?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Rewrite:
$$
\large x^x+\ln x^{\Large x^x}=x^x+x^x\ln x=x^x(1+\ln x)=e^{x\ln x}(1+\ln x).
$$
Let $y=x\ln x$ and $dy=(\ln x+1)\ dx$, therefore
$$
\large\int_1^e\left(x^x+\ln x^{\large x^x}\right)\ dx=\int_{x=1}^e e^y\ dy=\left.e^{x\ln x}\right|_{x=1}^e=\large\color{blue}{e^e-1}.
$$

Comment: Also the answers of me and lab were downvoted, but $10-2>0$.

Answer (score 4):

$$\int_{1}^{e}x^{x}+\ln x^{x^{x}}dx=\int_{1}^{e}x^{x}\left(1+\ln x\right)dx=x^{x}\mid_{1}^{e}=e^{e}-1$$

Here $x^{x}=e^{x\ln x}$ and its derivative is $e^{x\ln x}\left(\ln x+1\right)=x^{x}\left(\ln x+1\right)$
(application of chain rule).

Comment: Nothing is wrong with this answer (if you do not agree then at least try to convince me), but still it was downvoted. No comment that makes clear why. Sad story.

Answer (score 3):

$$\ln(x^{x^x})=\ln\left[(x)^{x^x}\right] =x^x\cdot\ln x$$

$$\implies I=\int_1^e(x^x+\ln(x^{x^x}))=\int_1^e x^x(1+\ln x)dx$$

Let $y=x^x\implies \ln y=x\ln x$ and $$\frac{dy}{dx}=x\cdot\frac1x+\ln x=1+\ln x$$

Comment: Also the answers of me and Tunk-Fey were downvoted, but $10-2>0$.